# copy/paste works with text but not with files

Tags: qemu, spice

I'm using Qemu to have a Windows virtual machine (which is integrated to an active-directory domain).
I want to copy/paste a file from my host (archlinux) to my guest (Windows 10 Business).

For that, I use `spice`.
Thus, I start qemu with the following command:

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm
  -cpu host
  -smp 4
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=OVMF.fd
  -vga qxl
  -device virtio-serial-pci
  -spice port=5930,disable-ticketing=on
  -device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0
  -chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,name=vdagent
  -m 16G
  Windows.qcow2
```

(line breaks inserted for readability)

Then, I use `spicy` to connect to it.

I installed `spice-guest-tools` on the guest Windows virtual machine.

The copy/paste works well for a text but not for a file. I use thunar as file manager on Linux.
Do you know why?

Also I don't want to use virt-manager.

Comment: What does "copy a file from Thunar" even mean? I mean, how would Windows interpret that? Can't you just `scp` or `rsync` the file over, or use a shared or network-mounted drive?

Comment: @Kusalananda, what I mean is: doing a right click on a file in thunar, then click on `copy`. Then go on my Windows guest Desktop, right click, Paste. I tried to use `-net user,smb=/tmp -net nic,model=virtio` but it does not work (and it is another question). copy/paste a file from Thunar works well with vmware, and I don't know why it does not work with qemu.